# Access to angular service in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-services

I am writing e2e tests in protractor for my angular app.

I have a process which the user enters some data at each step and I use a service to hold this data and pass the important parts tot eh next step in the process via getter and setter methods.

I cant seem to get protractor to call these setter methods before calling browser.get and therefore the page does not load  properly.

Below is some stripped back code.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Process step 1 - sets the data via quotesService setter methods

```
function _check_property_type(question, answer) {
        if (question === 'property_type') {
            $scope.borrowing_soon.is_required = true;
            quotesService.setPropertyType(answer);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function _check_reason(question, answer) {
        if (question === 'reason') {
            $scope.property_type.is_required = true;
            quotesService.setReason(answer);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Process step 2 - gets data from quotesService via getter methods

```
data.reason        = quotesService.getReason()      
data.property_type = quotesService.getPropertyType()
```

quotesService

```
var propertyType;
var reason;

function setPropertyType(answer){
    propertyType = answer;
}

function getPropertyType(){
    return propertyType;
}

function setReason(answer){
    reason = answer;
}

function getReason(){
    return reason;
}
```

Protractor test

```
function get(reason, property_type) {
    browser.get(
        'quotes.html#/step_2'
    );

    **** Need to set the variables here. ****
    --------
    // this is how its done for cookies.
    // browser.manage().addCookie('reason', reason);
    // browser.manage().addCookie('property_type', property_type);
    --------
    browser.refresh();
}
```